# WP Links from Facebook and Google Ads shows invalid characters

Tags: encoding

So Worpress site. Links from Facebook and Google ads shows invaild caracters at accented letters. From Microsoft Edge looks OK, but from Google Chrome not OK. After click an internal link the site goes to normal.
Can you help me please?
https://foresta.hu/?fbclid=IwAR1v8fQXY7-E-XhTgE-YX-nO0O8Eq-M1v661mgRQv-WDaNadOFD2KYX_igo
[image: bad caracters]

Comment: Mowar, you have no idea how grateful I am to you :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be caused by WP Rocket. Turn it off to confirm it, and then you could try out this:
https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/64-fix-utf-8-issue-with-special-characters